# Installation ArCore on samsung s9 960f for developing app

Tags: arcore

I really want to start writing applications for arcore. I have a Samsung 960f phone, the European version which is not supported yet by ArCore. Is it safe to install software by downloading Apk? I am afraid that I will burn the phone. Has any of you installed it?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed ARCore from APKs, but they don't work on the S9 Plus. That should be the same for the S9.  There's a driver issue they need to resolve. I haven'tseen a clear ETA on that though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for reply ;) I've installed ARCore 1.0 from APKs and it works fine